# Hidden Personal Macro Workbook Opens upon running macro to close ActiveWorkbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a macro that I have coded to close the activeworkbook after running a series of formatting and saving it as a PDF. However, it opens a hidden version of the personal macro workbook immediately after and I'm not sure why or how to stop it from doing that.

Can anyone assist on the why or maybe the VBA code should be different?

[Picture of Hidden Workbook Appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzhoe.jpg)

The First portion I believe may be the reason why it may be doing this but can't prove it yet.

```
        If closeOption = vbYes Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
```

FYI, the Personal Macro Workbook is already hidden so that is not the issue.

Below is the entire code:

```
Sub ActionItemReportPRO()
    ' Prompt for Report Type and Association Name
    Dim associationName As String
    associationName = InputBox("Enter the Association Name:", "Association Name")
    Dim reportName As String
    reportName = InputBox("What Kind Of Report Is This?", "Report Type", "ACTION ITEM REPORT")


    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Select
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .WrapText = True
            '... (other cell formatting)
        End With
    End With
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        '... (other page setup configurations)
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterHeader = "&""-,Bold""" & associationName & Chr(10) & reportName
        .LeftFooter = "&B Confidential&B"
        .CenterFooter = "&D"
        .RightFooter = "Page &P"
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$1"
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 0
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView
    
    ' Default file name
    Dim pdfFileName As String
    pdfFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", Title:="Save As PDF", InitialFileName:="17 AIR")
    
    If pdfFileName <> "False" Then
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        
        
        ' Ask if the user wants to close the file
        Dim closeOption As VbMsgBoxResult
        closeOption = MsgBox("Would you like to close this file?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Your File Has Been Saved!")
        
        If closeOption = vbYes Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Show the whole code!

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I just changed it. Let me know if this helps address the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using VBA to close the only open workbook outside of PERSONAL.xlsb. In which case, your hidden workbook isn't "opening" - it's already open in the background. You can actually duplicate this experience by hiding the only visible workbook as well.

If you want Excel to close completely, add this to the end of your code.

```
If Workbooks.Count = 1 Then
    Application.Quit
End If
```

This should only close Excel if the only remaining workbook is PERSONAL.xlsb.

CAUTION:
This will force-close VBA as well. Any changes you make to your code will need to be saved or discarded when you perform this step. You risk losing unsaved code completely.

Happy trails!